# Get exit code from subshells that are running in parallel

Tags: bash, shell

I try to make a shell script to launch a serie of long-runner processes. Let's call them a, b, c, d and e. Processes b, c and d should run in parallel, and process e must run after all of the previous ones have terminated *successfully*.

There is my (pseudo-)code :

```
{
    echo "starting a"
    a
}&&
{
    (echo "starting b"; b; exit $?)&
    (echo "starting c"; c; exit $?)&
    (echo "starting d"; d; exit $?)&
    wait
}&&
{
    echo "starting e"
    e
}
```

My problem is, if any of b, c, d fails, the script continues and executes e. Is there a way to prevent that?

Huge thanks for any answers !

Antoine

Comment: `(echo "starting b"; b; exit $?)` - the `exit $?` is definitely redundant. You can leave it off and the subshell will return exit code from b anyway.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356100/how-to-wait-in-bash-for-several-subprocesses-to-finish-and-return-exit-code-0

Answer (score 2):

```
{
    (echo "starting b"; b)&
    (echo "starting c"; c)&
    (echo "starting d"; d)&
    wait %1 && wait %2 && wait %3
}&&
```

when waiting for a specific job `wait` returns this jobs exit code

**To Understand look at these two examples:**
only the last line is important (shows exit status of `wait`)

```
(sleep 3; false) & wait; echo $?
[1] 25358
[1]+  Exit 1                  ( sleep 3; false )
0
```

--

```
(sleep 3; false) & wait %1; echo $?
[1] 25362
[1]+  Exit 1                  ( sleep 3; false )
1
```

Comment: This will wait for all processes to complete, but does not capture the ir exit status.

Comment: @HenkLangeveld: I have updated my answer in response to your objection

Answer (score 0):

By running a process in the background, you've basically told the shell that you're not interested in its success or failure.

`wait` *will* report the value of any signal in its exit code, if that applies.  This is not what you're looking for.

A solution would be to have each command report its status to stdout
and count the responses with grep.

```
{
  (echo "starting b"; b && echo ok)&
  (echo "starting c"; c && echo ok)&
  (echo "starting d"; d && echo ok)&
} | 
grep -c ok | ( read n && (( n==3 )) ) && 

{
echo "starting e"; e
}
```

Comment: In `ksh93`, `grep -c ok | read n && (( n==3 )) &&` would work as well.